# Unrecognized option '-enable-libx264'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm trying to stream MP4 videos from my server to YouTube and so I installed FFMPEG version. When I then look at the configuration of FFMPEG, I am then presented with the following:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --enable-cross-compile --arch=i686 --target-os=linux --disable-yasm --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl --disable-decoder=ac3 --disable-decoder=ac3_fixed --disable-decoder=eac3 --disable-decoder=dca --disable-decoder=truehd --disable-encoder=ac3 --disable-encoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=eac3 --disable-encoder=dca --disable-decoder=hevc --disable-decoder=hevc_cuvid --disable-encoder=hevc_nvenc --disable-encoder=nvenc_hevc --extra-ldflags='-L/root/daily_build/64_05/4.4.1/LinkFS/usr/lib -L/root/daily_build/64_05/4.4.1/Model/TS-X72/build/RootFS/usr/local/medialibrary/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/medialibrary/lib' --extra-cflags='-I/root/daily_build/64_05/4.4.1/LinkFS/usr/include -I/root/daily_build/64_05/4.4.1/Model/TS-X72/build/RootFS/usr/local/medialibrary/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -DQNAP' --prefix=/root/daily_build/64_05/4.4.1/Model/TS-X72/build/RootFS/usr/local/medialibrary
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
```

However, when I then try

`ffmpeg ---enable-libx264`

I then get an error saying:

```
Unrecognized option '--enable-libx264'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Do I need to change the configuaration of FFMPEG somehow or run another configuration option first or is there just something wrong with my call to enable libx264?

Comment: These are build system options that were used when compiling ffmpeg. They do not represent actual options recognized by ffmpeg.

Comment: So are you saying that ffmpeg was compiled/installed with the list of system options?

Comment: And If I wanted to add --enable-libxcb as a system option, would I have to reinstall or recompile FFMPEG or would I have to install another library or dependency?

Comment: These are options passed to the build configuration script of ffmpeg. If you want to change that, you need to build ffmpeg from source code and pass that option to the build configure script.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version that doesn't have libx264 support (Like Nikos mentioned) (which is rather old as well)

You must recompile it with the needed codec(s).

You could try using the below script, or compile it yourself.

I would recommend since will need to build your own, that you also add support for hardware encoders/decoders if you have a recent NVIDIA card --enable-nvenc and use h264_nvenc instead of libx264 for encoding to reduce CPU overhead.

Final thought - Would OBS fulfill your needs?

---

OBS streaming info

https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-live-stream-on-youtube-with-obs/

Compiling info..

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Script

https://gist.github.com/silverkorn/db5451f836e2bf9dea2a8358475eb5f4

Comment: Yes Don OBS would work and we already have a laptop running it that is then connected to the server which then has the videos on it. However, the problem is we have to hard wire the laptop in to the server as otherwise the stream drops frames which then means it can't be used for anything else.

So we were trying to see if we could get the server (which is a QNAP NAS with no graphics card) to run the stream on its own. We tried installing OBS but it was only possible through a horrible VM interface so thought FFMPEG might be the best solution.

I'll have a look at the script you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ffmpeg` already has libx264 enabled. Refer to the `configuration` line and you can see `--enable-libx264` is listed.

To use it:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

To stream a MP4 file to YouTube:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 8000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://youtube
```

From [FFmpeg Wiki: Streaming](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).